# Hbase Importtsv line termination

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How can I specify line termination as '\r\n' in importtsv command? I get number of rows as 145M after command completes however it is really 6M .

Answer (score 0):

you can not specify the line termination in import tsv.

However you can easily change your line termination in the file using sed.

You should read [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv) which will give you examples and all the information you need to import tsv to hbase.

Comment: Where can I change this parameter?